# SweetAlert2, .then() - not updating DOM immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2

**THE PROBLEM:**
I want to redirect a user to another page after clicking OK on the sweet alert, but the user is not redirected until I open up another sweet alert for some reason.
You can breakpoint over the code, but nothing happens on the page.

Simple example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/14306/

**NOTE**: including a 0 second timeout "solves the problem"

To Reproduce:
1) Note the text after the arrow.. $scope.name = "original", and you can see it's displayed on the page.
2) Click the "click first" button. This runs the function $scope.changeMe(), which updates $scope.name to "delayed......."
3) By now, the text above the buttons should have been changed. But it's not until you open up another sweet alert does the text actually change
4) Click the "then here" or "click first" button so another sweet alert pops up, and the DOM will finally change.

I'm pretty sure this is somehow related to AngularJS, and 1.4.3 has to be used.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
    <button ng-click="changeMe()">click first</button>
    <button ng-click="decoy()">then here</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="reset()">reset text</button>
  <div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.name = 'original';
    $scope.copy = angular.copy($scope.name);

    $scope.changeMe = function() {
      swal("Text should change now")
      // runs on hitting "OK"
      .then(function() {
                  // UNCOMMENT THIS and re-run the fiddle to show expected behavior
          // $timeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false; }, 0);
          $scope.name = 'delayed.......'
      })
    }

    $scope.decoy = function() {
        swal("Look at the text now");
    }

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.name = $scope.copy;
    }
})
```

Comment: Unless the SweetAlert library was designed for Angular, it will operate outside the Angular context. Angular's digest cycle must be called for changes to take effect. `ng-click` applies the digest cycle, which is why you see the changes after the second click. `$timeout` also calls the digest cycle. See your example with `$scope.$apply()` added: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/14313/

Comment: [ngSweetAlert](https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert) is the way to go if you want proper integration with angular, otherwise you will have to manually notify angular of such model changes using `$scope.$apply()` as @AlexK mentions above.

Comment: @AlexK that exactly solved my problem. I created an Angular wrapper factory which calls that every single time we use a sweet alert. Thanks for your help! Thanks for the confirmation Matthew Cawley !

Comment: Very well worded, question. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some problems in your fiddle

1)swal is not an angular library. So it won't work along with angular digest cycle, that is why it works only after $timeout is called.
[this](http://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html) tutorial explains why and how to fix it.

2)I see you have added [ng sweet alert](https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert) as a dependency but that is called before angular, so it doesn't not register in your fiddle and there is a console error.

3)If you were trying to use ng-sweet-alert it doesn't use this syntax. You need to include it in depedency first

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['oitozero.ngSweetAlert']);
```

And it doesn't return a promise and it needs to be called differently.

```
SweetAlert.swal("Here's a message");
```